# Proposition about intersection of connected sets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $X$ a connected topological space. Let $A,B\subset X$ closed subsets with $X=A\cup B$. Proof this proposition: If $A\cap B$ connected $\Rightarrow$ $A$ and $B$ are both connected.

I understand this proposition descriptive but I don't get a beginning to proof this. Any hints for starting or solving?

Comment: I would try a *reductio ad absurdum*: Start with the assumption that either $A$ or $B$ is not connected, i.e. there is a partition into to disjoint open sets. Then you have to show somehow that $X$ cannot be a connected set itself. Mostly this is easier since connectedness is an excluding definition (you define what it means not to connected).

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, Jakob! I'm not sure, if I understand your idea correctly: First step is clear, maybet let $A$ not connected. Why I can conclude with $X$ that $A$ and $B$ have to be connected?

Comment: See the latest answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aruging via contrdiction. If $A$ is not connected, there exist two closed and disjoint subsets $C,D$ of $A$ such that $A=C\cup D.$

Since $X$ is connected, we have $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$. With no loss of generality, we may assume that $B\cap C\neq\emptyset$. Observing that $A$ is closed in $X$, both $C$ and $D$ are closed in $X$. We note that $$A\cap B=(B\cap C)\cup(B\cap D)$$ is connected, we obtain $B\cap D=\emptyset$. However, we have $$X=A\cup B=(B\cup C)\cup D,$$ and $B\cup C, D$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$, a contradiction to the connectedness of $X$.

Comment: Thanks, user! I have some questions: (1) Why we can assume $B\cap C\neq \emptyset$ with no loss of generality? (2) Why we obtain $B \cap D=\emptyset$, what's the reason for that? (3) Why $B\cup C$ and $D$ are disjoint subsets? Can I conclude this from the disjoint partition $C\cup D$? But why $B$ and $D$ are disjoint? (4) And we can assume $B$ is connected?

Comment: @jacmeird I am sorry for my unclear proof. As to your first question, it is because of $A\cap B\neq\emptyset.$ If $B\cap C=\emptyset$, then we have $B\cap D\neq\emptyset.$ As to your second question, since we have assumed $B\cap C\neq\emptyset,$ if we also have $B\cap D\neq\emptyset,$ then $A\cap B$ is not connected.

Comment: @jacmeird As to your third question, it is easy to check.

Comment: @jacmeird As to your last question, it is not necessary.